# amd64-microcode installation during the latest 16.04 updates

Tags: microcode

Does anybody know why the `amd64-microcode` package gets installed automatically on systems that use Intel processors during the latest 16.04 updates on May 22, 2018?

Comment: Hm.  ```apt-cache rdepends amd64-microcode``` suggests that only ```linux-image-oem``` depends on that package.   Do you have that installed by any chance?

Comment: I am using `intel-microcode` since my systems use Intel CPU's. Today though, I saw that along with the new 4.4.0-127 kernel `amd64-microcode` got installed as a new package on two systems. I am using the `linux-generic` kernel.

Comment: Isn't that the fix for the meltdown bug that was found in Intel CPUs?

Comment: @dsstorefile1, No. I can't even find that package in the repos. Only `linux-firmware` is installed.

Comment: @Stormlord: my bad, I accidentally checked on 18.04 dependencies.  Right you are about the 16.04 kernels having an amd64-microcode dependence.  I guess that the LTE kernel packages _should_ depend or at least recommend the latest microcode for the arch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a new dependency of `linux-image-generic`. See
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/+bug/1738259.

Comment: You're right. It looks like both intel and amd64 microcode packages are mandatory from now on.

Comment: @ubashu: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering the reverse: why my amd processor got an intel microcode update, and this answers that as well.